# open a customized pop up window without address bar using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to open a new pop-up window without address bar and i need to display some data in that window. I should be able to modify the data in the pop-up window and once i click on "ok" the pop-up should get closed and the data should get passed to the parent screen which opened this pop-up . Also the popup should have the same css as the parent window .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using a [modal window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) instead of pop-ups for providing a more decent user experience. You can easily do what you want with a [jquery](http://jquery.com/) plugin like [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/).

Answer (score 0):

`onclick="window.open('abc.php','addressbar=no')"` should do